# Leaflet markers not showing

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, leaflet, mapping

The markers from leaflet map are reading from a postgresql query, which is influenced by filters on the page that the map is on. However whenever I open this page, with or without the relevant filters, only the first 3 or 4 markers will show up on the map while the rest do not. My query pulls way more locations than the ones that actually get displayed. Aside from this I have the TypeError illustrated in the screenshot. In this example TypeError repeats itself 14 times. Where might I be going wrong?
[image]

Comment: Check the objects in the array you logged in the line 391 of the script filteranalytics.js.
It looks like the lat info is missing, maybe because of it's not on the DB or because it's not being properly set in the JS object.

Comment: Yes just tried to add an extra where clause to only return results with co-ordinates since not all locations have this and it works just fine now thanks..